# Find the extremas of $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}$ subject to constraint $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ using Lagrangian multipliers.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the extremas of $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}$ subject to constraint $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ using Lagrangian multipliers.

---

My attempt: We introduce the following function, then use Lagrangian multipliers
$$L(x,y,\lambda)=\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\lambda(x^2+y^2-r^2)$$
Computing partial derivatives,
$$L_{1}(x,y,\lambda)=\frac{1}{a}+2x\lambda=0$$
$$L_{2}(x,y,\lambda)=\frac{1}{b}+2y\lambda=0$$
$$L_{3}=0 \iff x^2+y^2=r^2$$
We have
$$x=\frac{1}{-2a\lambda}, \hspace{2mm} y=\frac{1}{-2b\lambda}$$
Using $x^2+y^2=r^2$,
$$\frac{1}{4a^2 \lambda ^2}+\frac{1}{4b^2 \lambda ^2}=r^2 \iff \lambda= \pm \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2abr}$$
Hence, we have that the values $(x,y)$ which maximizes the function is
$$x= \mp \frac{br}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \hspace{2mm} y= \mp \frac{ar}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
Inserting the values into the function, we have that
$$f(x,y)_{max}=\frac{2abr}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \hspace{3mm}f(x,y)_{min}=\frac{-2abr}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} $$
However, the answer states that
$$f_{max}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{ab}, \hspace{3mm} f_{min}=-\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{ab}$$
Where did I go wrong/ how can I simplify further

Comment: You can do this with much simpler techniques. Hint: where is a line of the form $x+y=c$, which has gradient $-1$, tangent to the circle, thereby orthogonal to a radius of gradient $1$?

Comment: @J.G. Yeah, but the question specified using Lagrangian multipliers, sorry! I will update the post.

Comment: I see. You may want to edit once more, as there's some inconsistency as to whether you're maximizing $x/a+y/b$ or, as per my previous comment whose strategy is easily generalized, $x/a+y/a$.

Comment: The answer you've been given dropped a factor of $r$, but is otherwise correct. I suggest you double-check your calculation of $x/a$ from $x$.

Comment: Your error seems to be here: "Inserting the values into the function, we have that ..." but you omitted those calculations, so we can't say where exactly you went wrong.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes! This was the error! However, I now obtain $\frac{r\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}}{ab}$. Maybe the answer is wrong?

Comment: @J.G. So you think the answer missed a factor of r?

Comment: They did. You can check this with dimensional analysis. But as mistakes go, it's easily done, especially given how often we set $r=1$ for "the" circle.

Comment: @J.G. Perfect! Thank you! I mixed up the parts When inserting the values… The result would be quite surprising if that factor was not there.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @jjagmath, the mistake occurs when entering the obtained values for $x_0$ and $y_0$ which optimizes the function. We have that
$$x_0= \mp \frac{br}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \hspace{3mm} y_0=\mp\frac{ar}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
Taking the positive values for the maximum,
$$f(x_0,y_0)=\frac{1}{a} \left( \frac{br}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right) + \frac{1}{b}\left(\frac{ar}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)=\frac{r(a^2 + b^2)}{(ab)\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{r\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{ab}$$
As pointed out by @J.G. , the suggested answer misses a factor of $r$ and we are done